# set the checkbox visibility to false and remove the expand icon for a node based on certain condition in Telerik RadTreeView

Tags: telerik, radtreeview

CheckBoxes="true" is set by default in a Telerik RadTreeView. But based on certain condition like if the resource id is 0 then the visibility of the check box must be set to false and the expand icon of the node must be hidden.

Comment: Which platform are you using? WPF? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be done by:

- iterating through the treeview nodes (when build), for example inside the NodeCreated event handler
- locating the checkbox inside when node via the Controls collection
- setting its visible property accordingly

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Following:

```
public void DisabledCheckBox()
{
foreach (RadTreeNode n in RadTreeView.GetAllNode())
{
if( condition)
{
n.Checkable=false;
}
}
}
```

regards